# Easily change service reference endpoints and local vars per server build automated

Tags: c#, automation, service-reference

I have a project that needs to be deployed on multiple servers.  Its the same code, only the endpoints are different.  Currently, I have to do the following steps:

1) Configure the service reference to point to the correct server
2) Comment out the current server, uncomment the next server (a local parameter for the binding):

```
//private string serverName = @"http://server1/service.asmx";
//private string serverName = @"http://server2/service.asmx";
//private string serverName = @"http://server3/service.asmx";
private string serverName = @"http://server4/service.asmx";
....

ServiceClass.ServiceClassSoapClient Mgr = new ServiceClass.ServiceClassSoapClient (basicHttpBinding, new EndpointAddress(serverName));
```

3) Rebuild
4) Publish

There are many (16) servers that I need to do this to, and it is taking a LONG time to manually do this to all of them.  Is there a way to do this automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you need to do is to store a string which is system-dependent, why not use the built in Application Settings?  This stores data on a per-system (or per-user) basis in AppData which is accessible via the My.Settings object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c9db58th.aspx

For example, you would create a `string` type application setting called `serverName` and at run-time you could configure this from within your application by reading/writing to `My.Settings.serverName`.  The value of `My.Settings.serverName` is then stored for each system independently and returns a value unique to that system (or user) depending on where your application is running and who is running it.

Comment: Its not storing a string, its using a string to create a service reference, then a soap client in the code.   Then the compiled code is published to a server for general consumption.  Multiple servers are running the same code, but they have different user data, depending on the task the team wishes to store.

Comment: If I follow correctly, then this will work - instead of using `new EndpointAddress(serverName)` to create the service reference you would use `new EndpointAddress(My.Settings.serverName)` which would dynamically return (at runtime) a different string for `My.Settings.serverName` depending on the system where the compiled program is running.  The value for the setting is loaded from (or written to) disk on the system at runtime from the application/user's AppData area.

Comment: Sorry, meant to add also that the `My` namespace is not exposed in C# - have to access it directly from `Properties.Settings` etc.  Following the links should help.

Comment: So then I would need to modify the settings for every server as well?  I dont understand how this is faster.  What about the service reference?  It wont change.  (One of the servers is a test server and WILL have a different signature for testing before deploying to the other 15 servers)  Just saying the reference needs to be updated too

Comment: No, you set it up once - that's it.  Think of it like a registry setting (it isn't, but it works in a similar way).  Then any time you run any version of your application on that system it will draw from the locally stored values for your `Settings` variables.  Like a global variable which stays with a user or system apart from your compiled executable but which it can access.

Comment: I use this for control systems, for example, where I have one application which deploys across a number of manufactuing systems.  I don't have to worry about individual machine settings - I recompile a new version and run it.  It draws machine dependent settings from the `Settings` stored on each system and keeps their individual configurations consistent from build to build (ie: which equipment is physically installed on each system, what server to report to, etc).

Comment: Recompiling an application in order to change settings is ... unusual, to say the least. Most people prefer to edit a config file.